# Herewith versus herein. In this situation, is one or the other more grammatically correct and/or sense correct?

Tags: adverbs, archaicisms, adverb-position

Without thinking, I typed to matt there

> Will do! I'll post it herein ..

But it gave me pause; I tapped edit and

> Will do! I'll post it herewith ..

Now I don't know which version of me had the better idea or was less wrong.

Further, since it's getting a bit archaic, it's hard to find relevant samples.

Does anyone have any thinking on this issue?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean future related? Are you saying you will do it _soon_?

Comment: What was the intended meaning? Did a dictionary help?

Comment: I must be a bit thick, so could you explain what you want your sentence to mean?

Comment: @alphabet ??  Surely you know what herein (or herewith) mean?  They both mean the same thing, essentially "in this document".  Of course, there are extremely subtle shades of meaning / grammar usage (as with any similes) - hence my question.  Is one or the other a grammatically poorer choice - some expert will know.

Comment: @fev ??  Surely you know what herein (or herewith) mean?  They both mean the same thing, essentially "in this document".  Of course, there are extremely subtle shades of meaning / grammar usage (as with any similes) - hence my question.  Is one or the other a grammatically poorer choice - some expert will know.

Comment: @Fattie "Herewith" means "together *with* this document," not "in this document."

Comment: Surely you know the difference between _in_ and _with_...

Comment: @fev - that's a very interesting point, good one, TY. But I'm not sure if that distinction carries through to the two words in question ... (after all, in and with are not even adverbs, right?)

Comment: @alphabet true, both could perfectly describe the situation of later adding a new answer to a typical internet QA (same applies to comments)

Comment: Will do: post-haste. [laughs] Frankly, neither herein or herewith work well here. I'll post it here.

Comment: Another occurred to me. I'll do it. **Forthwith**.

Comment: @Lambie it's head of a pin stuff but "here" is for me "the environment" (ie, all of the SO programming site)  Perhaps "I'll post it on this QA" or ".. this screen".  Tortured analogy, "I'll post it here" would be like guys in a magazine publishing company saying "I'll write about it here" (ie, it will appear in one of our many magazines, here in our company) rather "I'll write about it in this one" whilst waving in his hand one of their particular titles.  Anyway!

Comment: Your meaning for these is: on this site?

Comment: If I understood your Q, I meant the "stackoverflow" (programmer's) site (ie, https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/fattie?tab=answers&sort=votes that site) Just IMO etiquette, idiom, behavior is different on the sundry "stack exchange" sites.  BTW forthwith makes me wonder about herewith.  I can't find any good etymology on these

Comment: Look, Fattie, I got two downvotes. Yes, too much French but provided the etymology and basically said the same thing the other answer said.

Comment: @Lambie voiting on this site has always been totally erratic (IMO).  U must havbe got three downvotes as I upvoted your answer!

Comment: Now, it's three dv's and counting. What a shame, huh? Rattles the bones, innit?

Answer (score 5):

If you want your comment to mean ***in** this document* (though you probably mean *in this post/in this OP*?), then use ***herein***, which is an abbreviation of ***in this***. (see [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herein))

***Herewith*** is more about *attaching* a message to a letter, doc, message and so on:

> ***together with*** this letter or other official written material:
>
> > I enclose three documents ***herewith***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/herewith))

I must say though that it seems to me a more complicated way of saying:

> Will do! I'll include it in the (OP/post/my answer etc.)

As you can see at the link provided, Cambridge labels this word as a *formal or specialized* term used for example in law.

Comment: Sure, it's legal but in daily  parlance all sorts of odd and quirky expressions are used in English coming from all sorts of fields/domains.

Comment: And sometimes people just enjoy a good word or turn of phrase. I happen to enjoy a "I am given to understand" from time to time.

Comment: Great answer TY!  However your suggestion part *"I'll include it in the (OP/post/my answer etc.)"* really doesn't work for me.  I'm not including anything; the verb post means "create an answer" {or indeed it could mean "create a whole new question" but that's not relevant in context, it can only mean "I'll post an answer on this QA"} {aside, it could mean "post a comment - but that only applies to people who sloppily add huge numbers of comments on SO :O } So post means "create an answer".  Where am I going to do that?  Herein. @fev

Comment: @Fattie You should have included all this information in the OP. You had me guessing what is posted in what or where... I am not saying it is incorrect to use quirky words. But if you are not sure of them or if they are too ambiguous, better make it make sense.

Comment: @fev well, maybe, but what's done is done. So - WTF right?!  :) It does seem very clear to me, there's literally an image of the whole interaction (perhaps it's more obvious to programmers-who-regularly-use-that-site the usual norms and interactions; sorry again!)

Comment: As fev suggests, neither **herein** nor **herewith** is suitable for online postings. It's not a matter of grammaticality but of register, and because they're *document*-centric or *text*-centric terms, not site-centric or forum-question-centric.  *I enclose herewith a self-addressed stamped envelope.* or *The subject is discussed extensively herein in Chapter 6.*

Comment: @TimR actually I agree with you - BUT - it's completely normal to use archaic, humorous, vulgar, legalistic etc words deliberately out of place - and **yet, still want to avoid grammar mistakes**. (TBC, I thought there might be a problem something to do with *tense*, or some other technical-sounding grammar term.) TBC, an answer I was expecting here would be something that reads like: "Fattie, you've fucked up again, it would have to be 'I'll post it herewith soon,' because the verb has no conjugate, you idiot"...

Comment: @Fattie There is no grammar mistake at all, with either one. It's just that there is a difference between a post and a text. That's the rub. It is *pragmatically, contextually or collocationally* inaccurate. Maybe: **hereunder** would do the trick for being legalese...

Comment: @Lambie *There is no grammar mistake at all, with either one* - well, great!  Really, that's exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

First the *distinction*:

> ‘**herein**’ means ‘inside here’, i.e. enclosed

> ‘**herewith**’ means ‘with this’ — not necessarily enclosed.

Second, the *“but you shouldn’t write that”*:

The information to be conveyed is that something is going to be sent to Matt. Hence both these words would seem unnatural when all that is required is the direct English statement:

> “I’ll post it to you (with the other stuff).”

*or*

> “I’ll include it in the box I’m sending.”

Not only only is it unnatural usage, but as the poster is referring to a future action (posting) it is unclear *where* the *here* in herein or herewith is.

When/how would you use herein and herewith? Only in the present tense. So they would be used in a letter sent in the post with the item in question. Examples are:

> “I attach/include it **herewith**.” — An additional document is stapled to
> this one or included in the same envelope.

> “You will find **herein** the goods as promised.” — This would be a note
> accompanying a box containing the goods.

But they still sound rather old-fashioned. Really only used by people of my generation.

**Postscript**

I have probably misunderstood the context of the question, in which “post” seems to mean publish something on SE. It should be evident from my answer that in that case I consider the use of either of these words would always be incorrect. The standard usage is explained in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate that this overlaps with the answer from @fev (which I didn't actually read while I was preparing this answer). My answer is distinct in its focus on tense, arguing that herein or herewith are not used in the future tense, but only in the present, and explaining that this is because of the "here-and-now". You pays your money, and you takes your choice.

Comment: Very interesting insight on the tense.  One issue is, say I'm holding a large legal file, sundry documents in it. You say "oh, you forgot the title deed" I say "damn, you're right, I will attach it herewith tomorrow"  Surely that is future tense?? Can any adverb be used with a future statement?  (Eg "I will carefully attach it tomorrow" "I will firmly attach it tomorrow" .. ??)

Comment: The order sheet shall be returned herewith [whatever that other thing is] to the distributor. //So, your thing about future doesn't really work...In any event, all these terms are used much more in things like contracts and laws than elsewhere, which was the whole point here. Also, I don't think the OP was sending something to Matt; she was posting to him online.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I wondered whether that would stand up. Clearly a more elaborate explanation of why the OP’s sentences are incorrect usage is required. Am I the one to do it? Not really, but I could have a try.

Comment: @Fattie But why would you write “herewith”? What do you mean by it? What is the “here”? Strikes me you just like the sound of the word.

Comment: hi @David , it couldn't be more obvious.  Right now we are using a specific internet page (to wit, english.stackexchange.com/questions/618531 )  If one of us used herein at the moment, it is referring to "this", ie english.stackexchange.com/questions/618531.  Note is there a chance you didn't actually glance at the question but only the answers (I often do that!) There is literally an enormous pink screenshot herein, showing what the question is about. (It's hard to imagine anything more "document like", the modern analog of a Victoirian era document, than a web page, I'd say.)

Comment: Correct, nothing to do with "sending" is involved.  I was going to post it {obviously as an answer - how else can you "post" something on a QA site? If it was a wikipedia format, it could me "edited in" but on a SO site, "post" means "post, create, submit, add, an answer"}  I'm 100% male just by the way  :)

Comment: Yeah, my point has been from the beginning that you meant underneath rather than with x or y. I know it's online post, not the mail (post).

Answer (score -3):

Sample:
"Will do! I'll post it *herein*..

But it gave me pause; I tapped edit and

Will do! I'll post it *herewith* .."

herein means *in the the text* and herewith means *appended to a text*, but these don't work for online posts. But there is no grammar mistake in either. They are just poorly collocated, or pragmatically/contextually inaccurate for an online post (as opposed to occuring in a text). Both terms can occur after a transitive verb or a be verb as adverbs. However, their semantic thrust does not work with them and the verb post.

**However**, if one is looking to be humorous or use a legalistic term for posting something below something else in an online forum *hereunder* works.

*Will do. I'll post it hereunder.

Online posts come one after another in a chat-type structure or even one with text boxes (like here). There something can be "hereunder".

Although [hereunder](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hereunder) means according to the terms of this document, because of the meaning of here and under, it works better for online chats/text boxes that come one under another.

Will do! I'll post it **hereunder**..

And to add some *charm*, I'll post it *hereunder and forthwith*.

**Anglo Norman Origins of words with *ci* (here in French) that persist in law and administrative law in English today**

> a. Anglo-Norman, Old English, Middle English words Alien, chose in
> action, demurrer, estoppel, Esquire, fee simple & fee tail, laches;
> metes and bounds, Oyez, quash, rol, voir dire, Aforesaid and
> forthwith, herewords: herein, hereby, hereafter…, Let (without let or
> hindrance), said and such (adjectives), Thence and thenceforth,
> there-words: thereby, thereafter…, Wherewords: whereas, whereby […]

[Anglo-Norman](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=383693a0b69de06da92a0d43349fe1d7e6aad66a)

Also, many words in legal-type English and legal English come from the French word **ci**, which means here. as in ci-dessous, in Anglo-Norman French: ci desuz.

Here is a slew of them:

[ci] here, in this place:
( 1113-19; MS: s.xii3/3 )  [...] En un livere devin Ki ad a nun Genesin. Ci recunted la sume, Quant que Deus fist pur hume  Comput ANTS 2001
( MS: 1120-40 ) Mercit, mercit, mercit, saintsimes hom! [...] Ci devant tei estunt dui pechethuor  S Alexis1 361
( s.xiiim; MS: c.1275 )  Ahy, sire, ke fetes vus ci?  Resur (C) 499
♦here, at this point:
( s.xiiiin; MS: s.xiii3/4 )  Ci en avez mester mult grant De beau solaz e de cunfort  Pet Plet ANTS 1206
♦in this (earthly) life:
( s.xii4/4; MS: s.xii4/4 )  Si sufferas mort trespassable, La averas vie parmanable  S Cath BARKING 579
( s.xiiiin; MS:    s.xiii3/4 )  Quant il en ert de ci parti […]  Pet Plet ANTS 1139
2 hither, to this place:
( 1121-25; MS: s.xiv1 ) La me mandat que ci venisse  S Brend MUP 1547
ci aloeces
here, in this very place:
( 1121-25; MS: s.xiv1 )  Ci aloeces fist atraire Mairen dunt sa nef fist faire  S Brend MUP 173
ci aprés
**hereafter**, **below**:
( 1325 )  La pacience ci aprés ensuant  Treaty Rolls i 260
( c.1396; MS: s.xv1 )  a fin de vous avertir a ce que ci aprés vous prieray  Lett & Pet 219
( 1433-34; MS:    c.1449 )  les joyaulx […] cy aprés specifiez  Bedford Inventories B154
**ci avant**
**from here on**:
( s.xiiex; MS: s.xiii2 )  Ore vus dirrai ci avant De seint G.  S Geo 73
**ci dedenz**
**herein**:
( 1113-19; MS:    s.xii3/3 )  La zone ardante […] nus fait Cez estencelemenz Que veez ci dedenz  Comput ANTS 404
( 1323-25 )  ci dedeinz enclos  St Sard 12
**ci desuz**
**hereunder**:
( 1318 )  la tenure de quele endenture est ci desoutz escript  Eng Docs 1.9
**ci (par) devant**
**formerly**:
( c.1192; MS: c.1275 )  De poestez que ci devant Orent li rei en lur vivant  Pr Jean3 143.Y1223
( 1404; MS: s.xv1 )  nostre pays sera en meillour gouvernance qu’elle n’ad esté cy devant en temps passé  Lett & Pet 344.19
♦earlier, above:
( 1113-19; MS: s.xii3/3 )  dunt jeo traitai Ci devant  Comput ANTS 2996
( s.xiiiex; MS: 1307-15 )  […] dont nus avom ci par devant parlé  Ancren2 204.17
**ci einz, ci enz**
here(in):
( 1354; MS: c.1360 )  cele vileyn qe dort cy einz  Sz Med1 62
♦in this court:
( 1309 )  nous mesmes recoverames […] par jugement de ci einz  YBB Ed II ii 103
**ci endreit, ci ore endreit**
**(here and)** now:
( c.1185; MS: s.xiiim )  Si vus volez ci ore endreit Mis hom ligement devenir  Ipom BFR 7032
( s.xiiiin; MS:    s.xiii3/4 )  Uncore dirreie ci endreit Mun avis  Pet Plet ANTS 879
**ci entre**
**herein**:
( c.1136-65; MS: c.1200 ) Oez que cist reis dit ci entre  Salemon 1819
**ci entur**
**hereabouts**:    [wow, great!!]
( s.xii3/4; MS: s.xiv2 )  treu demande de moy […] Od si feble gent qe meinent ci entur  Rom Chev ANTS 1485
ci qu’a
from here to:
( c.1200; MS:    s.xiii3/4 )  N’ad si fol si k’a Pavie K’ele ne feist sage  Josaphaz2 722
♦as far as, up to:
( 1214-16; MS: s.xiv1/4 )  levoyt ben un chivaler de tere sur sa paume si ke a soun chef  Turpin 967
**ci qu’a, de ci qu’a**
**between now and, until**:
( c.1185; MS: s.xiiim )  Cumbatre se deit mun seignur Pur la Fiere ci ke a terz jur  Ipom BFR 8466
( c.1185 )  Jol quid rendre sains e delivre De cest jor d’ui ci qu’a deus meis  Proth ANTS 2441
♦for (the next):
( c.1185 )  E vus ci ke a set anz avant M’en tendriez a recreant  Proth ANTS 9195
( 1312 )  qel oure qe vous perdisetz ci qe a .C. aunz  YBB Ed II xii 133
**de ci**
**following, next**:
( s.xivin; MS: s.xivm )  Aprés le tierz jour de ci la voiz fust oye  BOZ Cont 141
**de ci en avant, des ci en avant**
**henceforth**:
( 1215; MS: 1226 )  [R]iens ne seit doné ne pris des ci en avant por le brief del enqueste  Magna Carta 360.36
( 1306 )  nous de ci en avaunt pur toutz jurs serroms foialx et loialx  Parl Writs 180
de ci la
until then:
( c.1170; MS: s.xiiiex )  par mei n’iert destrier de ci la chevauché  Horn 4394
de ci qu’a, de ci qu’en
from here to:
( c.1170; MS:    s.xiiiex )  tiel n’en ad de ci qu’en Palestine  Horn 961
( c.1245; MS:    c.1255 )  Joe ne crei plus beaus seit de si qu’a Besençon  S Edw PARIS ANTS . 612
♦**until**:
( s.xiiiin; MS: c.1300 )  grant joie ad demené de si ke al jur ke estoit nomé  Boeve 119
**entre ci e, par entre ci e** […]
**between now and**:
( 1359 )  […]: q’ils les gardent a votre oeps parentre ci et l’Ascencioun proschein  ROUGH 148
( 1372 )  si le dit J.C. paie […] c. mars […] entre cy et la dit feste de Saunt Michel  GAUNT1 i 76
( 1377; MS: s.xv1 )  les profitz et revenues que purront estre leveez […] entre cy et la feste de seint Michel proschein venant  Lett & Pet 165.106
entre ci e la
between now and then:
( 1318 )  selonc ce qe les busoignes cherront entre ci et la  Eng Docs 4.37
**ci qu’atant que**
**until such time as**:
( 1272 )  ke il soit engeté hors de la communauté de la vile ci k’ataunt ke il gré feit  Bor Cust i 116
ci la que, de ci la que
until:
( s.xii3/4; MS: s.xiv2 )  n[’i] ad resne tenue De ci la qe la gent seit trestote venue  Rom Chev ANTS 7254
( c.1230; MS: s.xiiim )  A nul jur n’iere mais haité, Si la que seie de els vengé  S Modw 8124
( 1307-10 )  issi qu’il ne poeit avoir sustenaunce de nul ami qu’il avoit cy la qu’il avoit fait seurtee […]  LANGETON 315.17
( 1321-22 )  R. & M. continuerent lur seisince [sic] de ceu manoir peisiblement, cyla qe […]  Rot Parl1 i 405
**de ci que, de ci a ce que**
**until**:
( 1121-25; MS: s.xiv1 )  Ne de peiner ne recrerrunt De ci que lur desir verrunt  S Brend MUP 1102
( s.xiii2/4; MS: s.xiii3/4 )  Si il est yver, metez itele cure desi a ce ke la plaie merde  A-N Med i 138
**(par) entre ci e la que** […]
**between now and until**:
( 1276 ) E nous dit ausi de par vous ke nous meissom peine en voz busoingnes entre ci e la ke l’autre Justice venist  Lett AF 15
( 1377 ) si aucun point soit obscure, qe elle point eu pointz y purront estre declarrez, par entre cy & le Parlement prochein  Rot Parl1 iii 15

All bolding and square brackets mine. [Some of the line cuts aren't great, too much work to add line returns.]
[Anglo-Norman Dictionary](https://anglo-norman.net/entry/ci_1)

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Fattie Does that mean you like it or not? That's the etymology of herein and herewith.

Comment: Dude "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" means: "Holy crap, what a mind-blowing answer, that's incredible, thank you so much!"  Everyone knows that man :)

Comment: too much French...

Comment: @Mari-LouA It was more complicated to remove the sentences than to highlight the terms, fyi.

Comment: The fact that this is downvoted is incredible.  I'll now use this as one of my commonly-shown exemplars of how voting on this situe is totally erratic.

Comment: @Lambie you know it's entirely possible but IMO the site suffers "velocity voting". the site is followed by numerous (excellent) students of English, *as well as* by a handful of crotchety (English language) authors, screenwriters, professors of English, etc.  Answers which are "formatted well and written well" get lots of votes, perhaps by well-meaning enthusiasts of the site. To test this I once put in an answer to a question which was completely unrelated (as if I'd accidentally answered the wrong question) but was beautifully bureaucratically written with references, etc (unlike my -

Comment: - usual offhand style full of caps, swearing, pink images, seething sarcasm, etc.)  it got a huge number of votes and was the top answer before I deleted it :) :) :)  anyway in general I feel it's reasonable to say this SE site is the paramount example of erratic voting. Each site has it's own style. For example the aviation site is IMO the most rational, well-behaved, skeptical, least political etc. Anyways. Such is life.

Comment: There is also the profoundly problematic epistemological issue of the nature of this site that it is *pure opinion*. Say someone asked "Do you spell it color or colour?" That is a completely debatable point and I 4 1 actually don't know the answer. Sure, you could search the internet or something and literally find out that it is more often spelled X, but who gives a fuck about the internet?  It's tricky.  Grammar, spelling etc is descriptive not proscriptive, unless you're French I guess.